# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. my data cannot load

Tags: angularjs, json, html, controller

I need help for solve my problems. I have problems with call data from backend. please tell me how I can get the data from backend.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

i think i have problems with my controller to load the data.

**api**

```
application.factory('API', ['Settings',
    function(Settings)
    {
        var api = {};

        api.projects                  = '/ppr/resource/misbactivecaseJPA';

        api.get = function(endpoint)
        {
            return Settings.host.concat(api[endpoint]);
        };

        return api;
    }
```

]);

**service**

```
application.factory('Project', ['$resource', 'API',
    function($resource, API)
    {
        return $resource(API.get('projects'), {
            Id: '@id',
        }, {
            delete: {
                method: 'DELETE',
            },
            get: {
                method: 'GET',
            },
            save: {
                method: 'POST',
            },
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
            },
            update: {
                method: 'PUT',
            },
        });
    }]);
```

**controller**

```
application.controller('Property_ProjectController', ['$location', '$scope', '$mdDialog' , '$mdMedia', 'Project',
        function($location, $scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia, Project)
        {
            $scope.limit = 50;
            $scope.page = 0;
            $scope.projects = [];

            $scope.query = {
                $: '',
            };

            $scope.load = function()
            {
                var options = {};
                options.limit = $scope.limit;
                if (++$scope.page > 1) options.skip = $scope.limit * ($scope.page - 1);
                Project.query(options).$promise
                    .then(function(projects)
                    {
                        if (projects.data.length < 1) return;
                        $scope.projects = $scope.projects.concat(projects.data);
                        $scope.load();
                    });
            };

            $scope.load();
```

**html**

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="projects in data = (projects | filter:query:regex | orderBy:'name')">
        <td>{{ projects.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ projects.code }}</td>
        <td>{{ projects.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ projects.address }}</td>
        <td>{{ projects.ProjectId }}</td>
        <td><md-button  class="md-icon-button"
                        ng-click="AddProject($event)"
                        aria-label="{{ 'action_edit' | translate }}">
                <md-tooltip>{{ 'action_edit' | translate }}</md-tooltip>
                <md-icon>edit</md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one line in your controller that uses the `.length` property, which is line number `20`. The problem is `projects.data` is `undefined`, thus it is showing the error `Cannot read property length of projects.data since it is undefined`. Thus, `projects` object has no attribute `data` since `projects.data` is undefined.

Comment: so now what must i do for solve this error, sorry for asking you. i'm just need solve this problems. i take many hours to solve this. but still cant work. can you show me the code and part must i change.

Comment: As the answer states, `projects.data` is undefined, so you must check what the API is returning; why could it be that it's returning something undefined, or even it it's ok for it to expect a property named `data` (can you ensure it exists?).

Comment: You need to check your API for that purpose.

Comment: i'm already check the API using postman. the data already showing. but i don't know why  my angular it's not work. now i try to create new API for this part.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps try using a success callback rather than attaching a "then" to the promise:

```
var ps = Project.query(options, function() {
  if (ps.length < 1) return;
  $scope.projects = $scope.projects.concat(ps);
  $scope.load();
});
```

"ps" should be an array (initially empty) and should be defined by the time the callback function is invoked.